# Android Studio all gms/firebase libaries must use the exact same version

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This is my Gradle:app file

[image: two muppets]

Error I get when I try to rebuild:
"All gms/firebase libaries must use the exact same version specification. Found versions 11.6.0, 10.2.0. Examples include com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.0 and com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.0"

Anyone know how to get rid of the error?

Comment: On top of that all your *support* libraries must use the same version. Better clean this up, `design` support library is mentioned twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `./gradlew app:dependencies` to see what your transitive dependencies are (this will show what lib is depending on `10.2.0` for example)

Comment: It was 'com.frosquivel:magicalcamera:5.0.3', but I need that camera. Is there any way I can use Magical camera and also Google play services?

Comment: @kac26 Try including the dependency for location with the newer version manually, as suggested by Rainmaker: `compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.0"`. It should "override" the transitive dependency.

Comment: @A.K.S.H I tried but i get the same error. Nothing changes.

Comment: @kac26 In that case try excluding the transitive dependency: `compile('com.frosquivel:magicalcamera:5.0.3') { exclude 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location' }`

Comment: @A.K.S.H in that case i got error "gradle dsl method not found 'exclude()'", but if I change the dependency to: compile('com.frosquivel:magicalcamera:5.0.3') { exclude(group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-location')  }, I get the same same error as on the beginning: "All gms/firebase libaries must use the exact same version specification..."

Comment: @A.K.S.H I solved it! I change the compile to compile('com.frosquivel:magicalcamera:5.0.3') { exclude(group: 'com.google.android.gms') } and it started working! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I also had same error for the dependency version:

```
compile com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.2'
```

I resolved it by adding this missing dependency:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.6.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see you add `com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.0` dependency in your gradle but not `com.google.android.gms:play-services-location` .Try adding `compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.0"` to your dependencies, sync and rebuild the porject and also clean up the mess with other dependencies