# all gms/firebase libaries must use the exact same version. Found versions 15.1.0, 15.0.2, 15.0.1, 15.0.0.

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, gradle

Trying to implement Firebase in my project.

Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.ghaleh.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
     }


buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-  core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
All gms/firebase libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 15.1.0, 15.0.2, 15.0.1, 15.0.0. Examples include com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:15.1.0 and com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:15.0.2
```

According to [Google's Maven Repository](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html) the latest version of `firebase-messaging` is 15.0.2 and I'm getting error for `firebase-iid:15.1.0`
So I cannot upgrade the `firebase-messaging` to a higher version or implement the `firebase-iid:15.1.0` to match the versions.

I've already tried other solutions recommended here: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49106463/all-gms-firebase-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version-specification-android), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47398016/android-studio-all-gms-firebase-libaries-must-use-the-exact-same-version), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50100108/all-gms-firebase-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version-specification/50100204#50100204) but non of them were useful.

I've also tried this (however it doesn't seem to be a proper solution):

```
implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2') {
    exclude group: "com.google.android.gms"
}
```

and I get this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForBazaarDebug'.
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to update `google-service` plugin to use:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.0'
```

to be able to avoid those errors, also upgrade to android studio 3.1

> If you're not using Android Studio 3.1 to develop your app, you will need to upgrade in order to get the correct version checking behavior within the IDE.

more information and steps to follow:

[Announcing new SDK versioning](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/announcing-new-sdk-versioning.html)

[Compilation failed to complete:Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzabn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50149266/compilation-failed-to-completeprogram-type-already-present-com-google-android/50149536)

Comment: Wow! I can't believe it worked! You saved my day. Thank You.

Comment: I tried all the answer out there, after I updated Android Studio, my issue was resolved. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for adding the link to the SDK versioning blog! Very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to update

```
1.Playservice library
2.build tools
3.gradle wrapper
4.AndroidStudio
5.Migration to androidX
6.build tool version
```

> I finally ended up with a proper build after doing this stuff !!!